# hibernate relate between 2 objects

Tags: java, hibernate

i'm using hibernate to get objects from the db with AliasToBeanResultTransformer.
for example:

session.createsqlquery("select col_1 col1 , col_2 col2 from table").setresulttransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(MyClass.class))

and MyClass has col1, col2 as members.

is it possible to do the following thing:
have a class MyClass that will have as member List
an populate this member with a list of related row from a related table, but without doing 2 queries and iterating a loop that will create the required object?

meaning, implement hibernate's relation between 2 entities, but with my own entities?

thanks.

Comment: Do you want the member of MyClass class as a "List" instead of two member variables "col1" and "col2"?

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll rephrase the questions. with AliasToBeanResultTransformer i can store a query result to an object that is not mapped bt hibernate. can i use AliasToBeanResultTransformer or something else to do this in a nested way? meaning, if a member of the object is an object itslef, that i want to relate to the original object?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I again got the question correctly. But in case you want something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    private ClassAnother;
}
```

meaning you would want the member of MyClass as ClassAnother instead of "col1" and "col2", then the answer is yet.

You just need to define the constructor such a way that it takes "col1" and "col2" as parameters.

Hope this helps!

Edit: As per your comment, your class would be:

```
class ClassA{
   private List<ClassB> classBList;
}
```

And you want to get it populated in a single SQL query. If this understanding is correct, this would not be possible because your resultset would return repeated column of field of ClassA for each record for ClassB.

Comment: assume you have 2 hbm files and 2 corresponding objects. they have one-to-many relation. if i usew these hibernate object and query on them - everything  is ok. Now, assume that i dont wont the whole object, but just 2 fields out of each object. Normally i would create a  new object, with the fields that i want, and use AliasToBeanResultTransformer. But here i cant do this, because its not normal fields. object A has a list of Object b. how can i make the query populate the list as if it was a normal hibernate query?

Comment: Yes ofcourse! i meant the above class to get populated using AliasToBeanResultTransformer method of hibernate to convert return fields from SQL query to java objects!

Comment: Ok, so i get it that it cant be done with AliasToBeanResultTransformer . my question is how can it be done in any other way?

Comment: 2 options. 1 - In case your SQL query returns records of ClassB(corresponding table in Database) with duplicate records of classB, then create a Class with columns union of required columns ClassA and ClassB. 2. Fire 2 separate SQL queries. (suggest 2). No other option.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to purely retrieve a list then this HQL should do the trick

```
select clasA.classBList from ClassA clasA
```

this query would fetch all entries of classbList property...